# Creating table with two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen previous threads. Followed them but here it gives syntax error:

```
        create table temp (name varchar(20), id varchar(128), hash varchar(128),  
INDEX id, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN  KEY (id) references user_record(userid), CONSTRAINT 
FOREIGN KEY (hash) references post_data(hash));
```

error:

```
     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id) 
references user_record(userid), CONSTRAINT FOREIGN ' at line 1
```

where is mistake?

Answer (score 1):

See the example below, this might help:
This is a user table:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
userid INTEGER(8),
email VARCHAR(30),
password VARCHAR(30),
createdat datetime,
PRIMARY KEY(userid));

CREATE TABLE profile(
userid INTEGER(8),
firstname VARCHAR(20),
middlename VARCHAR(20),
lastname VARCHAR(20),
city VARCHAR(20),
state VARCHAR(20),
country VARCHAR(20),
zip INTEGER(5),
PRIMARY KEY(userid),
INDEX(userid),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES user(userid));

CREATE TABLE tags(
tagid INTEGER(8),
tagname VARCHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY(tagid));

CREATE TABLE notes(
notesid INTEGER(8),
notes VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES user(userid),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(tagid) REFERENCES tags(tagid));
```

the key that you are trying to make it foreign key in the child table should have it as primary key in the parent table. Otherwise you might get errors.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, FK in in my child table are PK in parent table. Can you see any syntax error?

Comment: can you by any chance provide your parent tables, so that it would be clear to find out the error

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error in your query is with the index part.

Change:

```
INDEX id,
```

To:

```
INDEX (id),
```